# Add text below icons in menu

Tags: html, css, menu, icons

I'm new to CSS and HTML. I've created a menu bar that contains 8 icons in a row. I want to add text centered below each icon, but no matter where I add the text in the HTML, it messes everything up. I've tried everything I can think of. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<div class="icon-bar">

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/ria-
stroke.png"></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon"         
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
ria.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/yoga-
stroke.png"></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
yoga.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/abit-
stroke.png"></span>
<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
abit.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<img class="esm-icon-active" src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/05/circle-esm.png">
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/pg-
stroke.png"></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
pg.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/lit-
stroke.png"></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
lit.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
 src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/1on1-
stroke.png"></span>  

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
1on1.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/education-
stroke.png"></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
education.png"></span>
</span></a>

</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#surround{
display:inline-block;
width:12.2%;
}
#onhover {
display: none;
}
#surround:hover span[id="initial"] {
display: none;
}
#surround:hover span[id="onhover"] {
display: block;
}

.icon-bar {
width: 100%;
overflow: hide;
padding-top: 7px;
background-color:black;
padding-bottom:100px;
}

.icon-bar a {
float: right;
width: 12.5%;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
}

.esm-icon {
opacity:0.5!important;
min-width: 55px;
max-width: 55px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 100%;
border: 2px solid transparent;
}


.esm-icon-active {
opacity:1!important;
min-width: 55px;
max-width: 55px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 100%;
border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x6pxj9L9/#

Comment: css3 has figure and figcaption, which may be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have a solution for you. First, I will attach a screenshot to show you the result of my solution and then I'll tell you what I did.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

The text I added under each icon was just "This is a test". Ok, now let me explain what I did and why.

Really it was basically 2 things that I did. The first thing was in your CSS code, I commented out 1 line. Here it is:

```
.icon-bar a {
/*float: right;*/
width: 12.5%;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
}
```

The "float: right" was the main problem. Unfortunately, I can't give a precise explanation why the float to the right was the issue, but I built a website a few months ago, where I had floated things in my navbar right, and the same thing happened to me.

I don't know if you were floating things right because you wanted the icons in a particular order but if that is the case, then rather than trying to get the order you want through floats (always a bad idea), I would just enter the icons into the code in the order you want them to appear in the first place. That will save you a lot of headache as a future practice.

I said there were two things I did. Here is the second...

I placed the text right after each icon in the code. Here is how I changed it. Take a close look at how I placed the text in the spans for the image that had a class of "surround".

**HTML**

```
<div class="icon-bar">

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/ria-
stroke.png"><p>This is a test</p></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon"         
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
ria.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/yoga-
stroke.png"><p>This is a test</p></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
yoga.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/abit-
stroke.png"><p>This is a test</p></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
abit.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<img class="esm-icon-active" src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-
content/uploads/2017/05/circle-esm.png"><p>This is a test</p></span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/pg-
stroke.png"><p>This is a test</p></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
pg.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/lit-
stroke.png"><p>This is a test</p></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
lit.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
 src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/1on1-
stroke.png"><p>This is a test</p></span>  

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
1on1.png"></span>
</span></a>

<a href="#"><span id="surround">
<span id="initial"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/education-
stroke.png"><p>This is a test</p></span>

<span id="onhover"><img class="esm-icon" 
src="http://treehouserecoverypdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/circle-
education.png"></span>
</span></a>

</div>
```

By putting the text right after the code for the image, the text would center itself under the icons by default, because you have the "surround" class displayed as "inline-block". Here is the CSS code... I did add a font color of "white" to the p tag, just so you could see the text:

**CSS**

```
p {
  color: white;
}

#surround{
display:inline-block;
width:12.2%;
}
#onhover {
display: none;
}
#surround:hover span[id="initial"] {
display: none;
}
#surround:hover span[id="onhover"] {
display: block;
}

.icon-bar {
width: 100%;
overflow: hide;
padding-top: 7px;
background-color:black;
padding-bottom:100px;
}

.icon-bar a {
/*float: right;*/
width: 12.5%;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
color: white;
font-size: 12px;
}

.esm-icon {
opacity:0.5!important;
min-width: 55px;
max-width: 55px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 100%;
border: 2px solid transparent;
}


.esm-icon-active {
opacity:1!important;
min-width: 55px;
max-width: 55px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 100%;
border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

I hope that helps! One more thing. I noticed that you have a "padding-bottom: 100px" in the CSS for ".icon-bar". Of course, if you don't like having that much space under the icons and text, you could just give it a padding of lik 20px or something.

Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate the help! I am still having an issues that I can't resolve, though. When I remove the float:right, the icons spill over to a second line. Any ideas how to fix this?:  https://jsfiddle.net/wqejrLz4/1/   Thank you again!!

Comment: I actually figured it out. I fixed it by adding white-space:nowrap. Thanks!